# Razorpay x Api call BAD_REQUEST_ERROR using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-curl, razorpay

I am trying to integrate razorpay x api for creating contacts and this is the sample api request data from razorpay. reference_id and notes are optional.

```
curl -u <YOUR_KEY>:<YOUR_SECRET> \
-X POST https://api.razorpay.com/v1/contacts \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "name":"Gaurav Kumar",
    "email":"gaurav.kumar@example.com",
    "contact":"9123456789",
    "type":"employee",
    "reference_id":"Acme Contact ID 12345",
    "notes":{
        "notes_key_1":"Tea, Earl Grey, Hot",
        "notes_key_2":"Tea, Earl Grey… decaf."
    }
}'
```

and below is my curl function data sent to razorpay.

```
$user=User::find($request->input('user_id'));
$payload= '{
    "name":"'.$user->name.'",
    "email":"'.$user->email.'",
    "contact":"'.$user->mobile_number.'"
    "type":"customer"
}';
$key="test_key";
$secret="secret_key";
$url = 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/contacts';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type:application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key . ":" . $secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting response as name field is required, eve though I have sent all the request fields in the request parameter. Please suggest me if my curl function is correct or not. below is the response from api call
    {
        "error": 
        {
            "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
            "description": "The name field is required.",
            "metadata": {},
            "field": "name"
        }
    }

Comment: Do not create your own json like this. Create an array with the proper data, then use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). That will ensure that your json is correct. (Which, by the way, is missing a comma between contact and type)

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: Read the link I provided, it has quite a few examples.

Answer (score -1):

Please specify the request method:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```